# How to get innerContent from element

Tags: javascript

I have this HTML CODE
I need to get from class="element"
 innerContent with starting like this `<th>Element 1</th>`

```
<table class="element">
    <thead>
        <th>Head of Element 1</th>
        <th>Head of Element 2</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th> Element 1</th>
            <th> Element 2</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I trued to get it like this:

```
var get = window.document.getElementsByClassName('element')[0].getElementsByTagName('th').textContent;
alert(get)
```

Comment: Did you check your console? You would have seen this: `window.document.getElementsByClassName(...)[1] is undefined`.

Comment: What is the expected result / what result do you get?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a **list** of nodes (getElement**s**ByTagName). Just use `document.querySelector('.element th')`.

Comment: Are you sure you want index 1? Arrays are 0 based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grabbing the first `</th>`

```
var get = window.document.getElementsByClassName('element')[0].getElementsByTagName('th')[0].textContent;
console.log(get)
```

Looping through the elements:

```
var get = window.document.getElementsByClassName('element')[0].getElementsByTagName('th');

for(var i=0; i< get.length; i++) console.log(get[i].textContent)
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, Javascript uses 0 based counting.  This means that the first of anything, is actually the number 0, 1 is 2, 2 is 3, and so on...

So we have to target the proper element here in the top.  Since there is only one child called 'element' here, you'll need to target it as the first item.

***However, if you already knew this.***  And this is actually the second child element.  Beware, because it could target the wrong element.

```
var elements = window.document.getElementsByClassName('element')[0].getElementsByTagName('th');

for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
  elements[i].textContent;
}
```

And since there are more than one child element, you're going to have to sort through them each.  To actually access their content.

This is represented by the for loop.

Hope this helps!

UPDATE:

A more advanced version based on Felix Kling's response that utilizes a bit less memory:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.element th');
elements.map( // Function or code to execute );
```